# Prove that the $\sigma$ - algebras are equal

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

I want to show that $\sigma$-algebras on $\mathbb{R}$ generated by $(a,b), \ (a,b], [a, b), [a,b], (-\infty, a), (-\infty, a], (b, +\infty), [b, +\infty)$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ are all equal.

Here is what I've come up with so far:

($\mathcal{M} $ - sigma-algebra)

Would it suffice to say that $\sigma$-algebras generated by $(a,b), \ (a,b], [a, b), [a,b], \ a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ are the same because

$(a,b) \in \mathcal{M} \ \Rightarrow \mathbb{R} \setminus (a,b) = (-\infty, a] \cup [b, +\infty) \in \mathcal{M}$, so $[a,b] = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N_+}} (a-\frac{1}{n}, b+\frac{1}{n}) = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N_+}} (\mathbb{R} \setminus (-\infty, a-\frac{1}{n}] \cup [ b+\frac{1}{n}, +\infty) )=$

$ = \mathbb{R} \setminus(\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N_+}}  (-\infty, a-\frac{1}{n}] \cup [ b+\frac{1}{n}, +\infty) ) \in \mathcal{M}$

Similarly, $[a,b) = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N_+}} (a-\frac{1}{n}, b)$, $(a,b] = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N_+}} (a, b +\frac{1}{n})$.

When it comes to $(-\infty, a), (-\infty, a], (b, +\infty), [b, +\infty)$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, would it be enough to say that $(-\infty, a) = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(-n, a)$ and etc?

In case of $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ would it be all right to say that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ so for every $r \in \mathbb{R}$ we will find a sequence $\{q_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ that converges to $r$, so for example $(r, b) = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(q_n, b)$ ?

Could you tell me if my approach is right?

Please, help.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes. Your approach seems fine. Except you don't need all those sets to get the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. For instance $[a,b) = \cup[a, b-1/n]$; so some of them are redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to show that any $\sigma$-algebra containing rational intervals must contain all real intervals.

You've got the right idea: the rationals are a countable dense subset of the real numbers, so you can always find a sequence of rational numbers converging to any real number, which you can use to construct countable unions and intersections to make all the types of interval you want.

Comment: All right. Thank you. Just to make sure - the fact that we can get each of the eight types of sets using other type of set and the conditions that a sigma algebra must satisfy says that all those sigma algebras are equal, is that true?

Comment: Any $\sigma$-algebra containing the rational intervals must clearly contain all sets that you can form by taking countable set operations of those intervals, so it must contain all real intervals (as you've shown), and therefore it must contain the $\sigma$-algebra generated by real intervals.  On the other hand, the set of real intervals contains the set of rational intervals as a subset, so the $\sigma$-algebra generated by real intervals must contain the $\sigma$-algebra generated by rational intervals.  Since the two $\sigma$-algebras contain one another, they must be equal.

Comment: Thank you again. One more question. Could you tell me how to quickly justify that $\sigma$ algebra generated by all $\{x, y\} \ \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ is $\{A \subset \mathbb{R} : |A| \le |\mathbb{N}| or |\mathbb{R} \setminus A| \le |\mathbb{N}|\}$ ?

Comment: You could ask that as a separate question, but the general method is: 1. Show that that set is a $\sigma$-algebra.  2. Show that any $\sigma$-algebra containing $\{x,y\}\forall x,y\in\mathbb R$ must contain every element of that set.

Comment: I won't ask a separate question. That's what I wanted to know. Thank you a lot for all your help.